# How to display images in multiple columns in a Grid View?

Tags: image, gridview, paging

I need to display thumbnails of images in a gridview in 4 columns like an image gallery. My image source is stored in a single column in my database. I will be binding those form a list. I have achieved displaying my images in a single column. But how to display my images in a multiple column in my grid view as an image gallery?

As an example, I have attached an image below.

[image: GridView Image gallery Mock]

This is how my images have to be displayed in my gridview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats impossible with a `asp:GridView` but you can easily achieve this using an `asp:ListView`.
For that you have to use [`GroupItemTemplate`](http://ListView.GroupTemplate%20Property) and `GroupItemCount` of the `asp:ListView`

Sample Code using `asp:ListView` with `asp:DataPager`

```
<asp:DataPager ID="TopPager" runat="server"
        PageSize="10"
        PagedControlID="ImagesList">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField PreviousPageText="Previous"
                            RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                            RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"
                            ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                            ShowNextPageButton="false"
                            ShowLastPageButton="false"
                            ShowPreviousPageButton="true" />
        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10"
                        CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current"
                            RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"/>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField NextPageText="Next"
                            RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                            ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                            ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                            ShowNextPageButton="true"
                            ShowLastPageButton="false" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
<asp:ListView ID="ImagesList" runat="server"
            DataKeyNames="MyImageID"
            GroupItemCount="4"
            OnPagePropertiesChanging="ImagesList_PagePropertiesChanging">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Images found.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="MyPicture" runat="server"
                    AlternateText='<%# Eval("MyAltText") %>'
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("MyImageUrl") %>' />
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
    <asp:DataPager ID="BottomPager" runat="server"
                PageSize="10"
                PagedControlID="ImagesList">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField PreviousPageText="Previous"
                                RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                                RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"
                                ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                ShowNextPageButton="false"
                                ShowLastPageButton="false"
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="true"/>
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10"
                                CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current"
                                RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"/>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField NextPageText="Next"
                                RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true"
                                ShowFirstPageButton="false"
                                ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
                                ShowNextPageButton="true"
                                ShowLastPageButton="false" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

And to implement paging, do this at code-behind

```
protected void ImagesList_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TopPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        BottomPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...It's working.. But i have plenty of images to display. Is there a pagination option for Listview as like in Grdiview. How can i handle paging here?  I need to display 4X4 = 16 images in the first page.Pls help me out on this too.